# Is there a way to bind Spring's modelAttribute returned by JSP to AngularJS model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring, jsp, jstl

I have Spring JSP returning Map of elements. The first approach was to use `JSTL` to populate select html element with options. Like this:

```
<select name="environment" id="environment" name="environment_name" class="form-control" ng-model="environment" required>
                <c:forEach var="environment" items="${environmentsMap}">
                    <c:if test="${environment!=null}">
                        <option value="${environment.key}"
                                <c:if test="${environment=='TEST'}"> selected="selected"</c:if>
                                >${environment.key}</option>
                    </c:if>
                </c:forEach>
            </select>
```

Front end uses AngularJS. Is there a way to bind returned Spring's model attribute to Angular model so I can populate select using Angular's `ng-repeat`?

Comment: No, you should rebind a model.